# CardMedia image doen't fit the Card Component (container)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, image, material-ui

I have a React App and I am using Material UI in it. I have a few toggle buttons on a screen. Within those toggle buttons I have placed a Card component (Container) to enclsoe an image in it using CardMedia component.
Image takes the full width of the Card component but does not fit with respect to the height. Following is the code:

```
 const ToggleCard = styled(ToggleButton)(() => ({
    background: "#fff",
    boxShadow: "0px 1px 2px rgba(85, 105, 135, 0.1)",
    borderRadius: "6px",
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    width: "200px",
    height: "100px",
    padding: "8px",
    "&.Mui-selected, &.Mui-selected:hover": {
        color: "#fff",
        backgroundColor: "#001d69",
    },
}))

const LogoHolder = styled(Card)(() => ({
    boxShadow: "none",
    background: "none",
    width: "150px",
    height: "80px",
}))

const Logo = styled(CardMedia)(() => ({
    width: "100%",
    height: "auto",
    objectFit: "cover"
}))

<ToggleCard value={bank.uuid} selected={selectedOpt === bank.uuid}
  onClick={() => handleSelectedOpt(bank.uuid)}
>
  <LogoHolder>
       <Logo component="img" image={bank.logo} />
  </LogoHolder>    
</ToggleCard >
```

[image: This is how it shows]

Comment: `object-fit: contain`

Comment: I have tried that too but it doesn't help.

Comment: A CodeSandbox reproducing your issue would be helpful for people to look at/debug. Without that, I'd suggest you look at the `overflow` property of `MuiPaper`/`MuiCard-root` that is most likely being set to `hidden`.